# Foundation CLI does not work. ReferenceError: primordials is not defined

Tags: node.js, npm, command-line-interface, zurb-foundation

I have Windows 10 (64 bit), Node v13.0.1, npm 6.12.0. I want to install foundation-cli globaly but I am getting "ReferenceError: primordials is not defined" while I command "foundation new" or "foundation -v". Please see my powershell message and tell me about the error and the solution.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> npm install --global foundation-cli
>>
npm WARN deprecated bower@1.8.8: We don't recommend using Bower for new projects. Please consider Yarn and Webpack or Parcel. You can read how to migrate legacy project here: https://bower.io/blog/2017/how-to-migrate-away-from-bower/
npm WARN deprecated natives@1.1.6: This module relies on Node.js's internals and will break at some point. Do not use it, and update to graceful-fs@4.x.
C:\Users\shams\AppData\Roaming\npm\foundation -> C:\Users\shams\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\foundation-cli\bin\foundation.js
+ foundation-cli@2.2.5
updated 3 packages in 12.24s
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> foundation new
fs.js:27
const { Math, Object } = primordials;
                         ^

ReferenceError: primordials is not defined
[90m    at fs.js:27:26[39m
    at req_ (C:\Users\shams\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\[4mfoundation-cli[24m\node_modules\[4mnatives[24m\index.js:143:24)
    at Object.req [as require] (C:\Users\shams\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\[4mfoundation-cli[24m\node_modules\[4mnatives[24m\index.js:55:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\shams\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\[4mfoundation-cli[24m\node_modules\[4mgraceful-fs[24m\fs.js:1:37)
[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:971:30)[39m
[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1011:10)[39m
[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:822:32)[39m
[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:730:14)[39m
[90m    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:864:19)[39m
[90m    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)[39m
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a known problem with NodeJS >= 12. Please try to switch to NodeJS 10.

Comment: At first I've installed node v12 and that's where the problem started. Then I thought maybe upgrading node will solve but still no luck.

Comment: You can use nvm for this.

Comment: I've installed NodeJS 10 and now it's working fine :D

Comment: Is this still an issue today? I'm seeing the same problem

Comment: Yes, we did not yet upgrade all the dependencies.

Comment: Is there a rough ETA for when Foundation will support Node 12?

Comment: So far there is no ETA.